# Reading CSV data where columns have numbers and characters

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to read a large csv data set with 7 million rows using the following code

```
histca <- data.table::fread("HISTO_CA.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Some of the columns have odd characters....see example below.

[image]

I get the following error code

> In fread("HISTO_CA.csv", select = c(1, 237:248), sep = ";", nrows =
>   1e+06,  : Bumped column 239 to type character on data row 198668,
>   field contains '™™?'.

Coercing previously read values in this column from logical, integer or numeric back to character which may not be lossless; e.g., if '00' and '000' occurred before they will now be just '0', and there may be inconsistencies with treatment of ',,' and ',NA,' t

How can I import the data and exclude the rows where this problem occurs

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data so we can have a look. Have you tried anything else (I'm thinking off the the top of my head the 'colClasses = "character" ' from read.csv)

Comment: Looking at `fread` documentation and its `colClasses` argument, we read: fread will only promote a column to a higher type if colClasses requests it. It won't downgrade a column to a lower type since NAs would result. You have to coerce such columns afterwards yourself, if you really require data loss. So I guess no direct solution with `fread`. I you want to stick to `data.table` I would suggest trying to clean the file outside R (are you working on Unix?)

Comment: I would try to read in all columns as character (using `colClasses`), to clean the data in `R` and to convert the columns to numeric after cleansing.

Comment: That is a warning, not an error, fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could read in the data as `character` class, and work from there:

```
library( data.table )
histca <- fread("HISTO_CA.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = "character" )
```

So you'll be bringing all of the text from the csv file into R without change. Then you can filter out any rows where, for example, `Col2` won't convert to `numeric` class:

```
histca <- subset( histca, is.na( as.numeric( Col2 ) ) )
```

Alternatively, you can keep those rows, simply replacing the offending values with empty character strings, which will convert to numeric as `NA` values.

```
histca[ is.na( as.numeric( Col2 ) ), Col2 := "" ]
```

( note this will spit back a warning that "NAs introduced", but that's what you want )

Then convert the entire column to numeric:

```
histca[ , Col2 := as.numeric( Col2 ) ]
```

Which will now have some `NA` values.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try this

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to come back and tell us how it went.

Comment: Thanks it works. I now have another problem related to this dataset.

Comment: I am trying to count the number of occurrences of a large numbers using this code... dt <- data.table(bkjan16)
dt[ , Index := 1:.N , by = c("ACCT_NUM" , "ACCT_NUM") ]
#convert data table back to data frame
bkjan16 <- data.frame(dt)
colnames(bkjan16)[colnames(bkjan16)== "Index"  ] <- "Runcount"
#rename index field to Runcount using fix
bkjan16.freq<-table(bkjan16$Runcount)
cbind(bkjan16.freq)

Comment: The numbers that I am trying to count using above code are very long for example 880566561284 and 880566561285. Instead of counting these as unique values r sees them as the sequential. Runcount should = 1 for both numbers but it equals 2 for the second number

Comment: @Manfred If this solution worked for your question, please mark it as accepted. You can ask a new question if there's something else you need help with.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)